# My Play! Application doesn't have an application.log

Tags: java, logging, playframework, playframework-2.2

I got an error message saying:

> This exception has been logged with id 1mhqg4onc

But I don't see this exception in the logs.

I only have `myapp.DEBUG`, `myapp.ERROR`, `myapp.FATAL`, `myapp.INFO`, `myapp.TRACE` and `myapp.WARN` in my `myapp/logs` directory.

I thought `application.log` was just supposed to be there by default. It's in my local machine but not when I deploy to production and that's where this exception is happening.

I tried adding a file at `conf/application-logger.xml` with the default logging configuration which includes info about application.log but I still don't have it.

I start my application in prod using the following in a shell script:

```
target/universal/stage/bin/myapp -Dhttp.port="${HTTP_PORT}" -Dconfig.resource=${CONFIG_RESOURCE}
```

I'm using Play! 2.2.1

Comment: Make sure you are looking in the correct folder: logs/application.log should be created in your current directory, so if you do `cd target/universal/stage/bin` and then run `./myapp` it will be located in `stage/bin/logs/application.log`. Also consider adding to your question  your logger.xml file and any log config you may have in application.conf

Comment: I ran the app manually and saw the exception printed out