# Why does my call to get using Play!'s WSRequestHolder make parts of my code not run?

Tags: java, logging, playframework, playframework-2.2

```
    WS.WSRequestHolder request = WS.url(url);
    logger.info("1")     

    final Promise<Result> resultPromise = request.get().map(
        new Function<WS.Response, Result>() {
            public Result apply(WS.Response response) {
                logger.info("2");
                try {
                    logger.info("3");
                    return ok(response.asJson());
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    logger.info("4");
                    logger.error(e.getMessage());
                    return status(response.getStatus());
                }
            }
        }
    );
    logger.info("5");
    return resultPromise;
```

For one particular URL, my code never enters the try/catch statement- it logs at point 1 and 5 though- what does this mean? That url hasn't returned anything yet? It works with other urls even if they return 400s or cause exceptions because of the format.

I've also tried to simplify it using:

```
    WS.WSRequestHolder request = WS.url(url);

    final WS.Response resultPromise = request.get().get();
    logger.info("Before result");
    logger.info("Res = " + resultPromise.getBody());
    logger.info("Before result");
    return null;
```

I don't see any of those lines logged with that particular URL. It worked with a URL where resultPromise.getBody() was empty

Comment: Don't you get any error message in the console?

Comment: @Salem What console? I do call this from javascript but that just gives a 500 since the request fails and the details are in the server logs but it just skips the error logs I've put in.

Comment: And you can't access Play logs? It's difficult to tell what is wrong without having the stacktraces or even the url you are trying to access...

Comment: @Salem  I don't have application.log in my logs directory- I've asked another question about why I don't have that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354148/my-play-application-doesnt-have-an-application-log

Comment: It was an ssl certificate issue

Comment: Could you please reply for this post asked by you before a year? http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/187804/what-is-meant-by-distributed-systems-coding-interview-questions